# How would I return a session Id to a mobile user authenticating via JSON?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Application host: MVC3 and SQL Server
Mobile platform: Android

Please tell me if this is the complete wrong approach.  I'm envisioning some sort of authentication process via an HTTP Post event.  The result (if successful) is a session Id returned so the user can call other secure methods.

Note: The controllers, database and JSON responses are already working in a non-secure way today.  I just need to add security.

If there is already a process for this please let me know.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use AspNet FormsAuthentication. Will provide an encrypted cookie. Used with HTTPS is a solid secure base authentication.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  When I attempt to call an authorize-only  method no JSON response is returned.  What should I do from the android app to make it return a response or set a session Id?

Comment: This is quite strange if you're sure you logged in.
Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to check headers (sent and returned)